# How to maintain historical data in oracle history tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am a testing engineer and working on an automation suit development. I am facing some problems for  generating reports of the test execution. My problem is :
Currently I am storing results of my test cases with some details in an oracle db table and then fetching these results to generate the report. Currently , I have around 50 mn+ records in my oracle table and this is making the report generation very slow.And I need to make it fast. I am thinkking of moving older data to historic table rather than working on my fetching technique as I am using another tool to fetch the results from table and generating report (and thus it is not in my hand).
Could any one tell me the technique to store the historical data in db. Previously , I had come across History tables which maintain a replica of data that the original tables have, but I don't exactly know how can I update them on regular intervals?

Comment: Maybe you can update them in a trigger. Every time you save new test results, you move the old results to the history table. Or save the results twice, once in the history table.

Comment: Do you user Enterprise Edition, and do you have the partitioning option licensed?

Comment: A trigger would run on every insert or update . I am looking for solution with which i can schedule data migration on per month or per week basis

Comment: 50mn records is not very much. Have you created indexes on the table? Post your table layout and a report query here maybe?

Comment: 50 mn records are created after one month of  test runs, records will multiply in next months as we will be running it daily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created Schedule using oracle scheduler. It helped me to avoid update on table after every new insert. I think  this is better way to do it than going for trigger.